# Comparing datetimes does not work

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm creating a Rails application which uses MySQL. I have a table in my DB like this:

```
  create_table "pastes", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "syntax"
    t.boolean  "private"
    t.datetime "expire"
    t.string   "password"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I want to show only the non-expired `pastes` to people, so I do this:

```
@pastes = Paste.find(:all, :conditions => "expire < '#{Time.now.to_s(:db)}'")
```

However, even that returns ALL `pastes`. Not just those that are not expired yet. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Oh, changing `<` to `>` returns no `pastes`, not even the non-expired ones :(

Comment: JFYI: it's cleaner to use `Time.now.to_s(:db)` than `strftime`

Comment: @neutrino thanks, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: yep, I didn't mean it would solve the problem. btw it's really weird cause I got a similar query working for my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it already. It had to do with timezones. This works:

```
@pastes = Paste.find(:all, :conditions => "expire > '#{Time.now.utc.to_s(:db)}'")
#                                                               ^^^ this does it
```

Comment: If you rewrite your condition to :conditions => ['expire > ?', Time.now] you don't need to convert to utc as ActiveRecord will handle that for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a named scope within your Paste model:

```
class Paste < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :expired, lambda {
    { :conditions => ["expire < ?", Time.zone.now] }
  }
end
```

Rails 3 version:

```
class Paste < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :expired, lambda {
    where("expire < ?", Time.zone.now)
  }
end
```

Note that the lambda is required to delay the evaluation of `Time.zone.now` until when the (named) scope is actually invoked. Otherwise, the time that the class was evaluated would be used.

Now you can get all the expired pastes with a simple:

```
@pastes = Paste.expired
```

—Pretty clean, huh?

Comment: This only causes confusion, since the expired pastes are only stored for spam-fighting. I'll never display them.

Comment: Who said anything about displaying them? Scopes are just a way of obtaining a subset of records using a convenient syntax.